# AWS Cloudwatch Logs Lambda Subscription getting triggered multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We are using Cloudwatch logs and wanted to do real-time log processing using AWS Lambda.
The Cloudwatch subscription is being triggered multiple times.
Is there a way to ensure only single trigger.

Comment: Please give more details and examples. If your subscription is getting multiple events, obviously it will get triggered multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to S3 in that you may get multiple invocations for the same event. You need to make your code capable enough to deal with this scenario. Caching a unique identifier or de-duping in some other way. Or just accepting that this will happen from time-to-time. Depends what your requirements are for the log processing.